# Flutter Testing: mocked shared preference instance method 'setString' is returning null

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, mockito, sharedpreferences, flutter-test

I have a mocked class like this:

class MockSharedPreferences extends Mock implements SharedPreferences {}

when I call setString class on the mocked instance like this:
mockedSharedPreferences.setString(key, value);

I get this error:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future'
package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart 115:16

getString() method is working in the mocked instance.

Anyone have idea that if setString() can be called in mocked SharedPreference class?

Comment: did you found a fix for you issue. I have the same currently experiencing.